# Tuning hyperparameters after multiple runs

Tags: machine-learning, python, cross-validation, hyperparameter, tuning

I wrote a classifier that uses LGBMClassifier. This is the code:

```
from lightgbm import LGBMClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupShuffleSplit
from skopt import BayesSearchCV

DEFAULT_PARAMS = {
        'class_weight': [None, 'balanced'],
        'boosting_type': ['gbdt', 'goss', 'dart'],
        'num_leaves': list(range(30, 150)),
        'learning_rate': [0.01,0.05, 0.1 ,0.5],
        'subsample_for_bin': [20000,50000,100000,120000,150000],
        'min_child_samples': [20,50,100,200,500],
        'colsample_bytree': [0.6,0.8,1],
        "max_depth": (5,100, 'uniform'),
        'lambda_l1': (0.7, 1),
        'lambda_l2': (0.7, 1)
    }

class LightgbmClassifier:
  def __init__(self, train_df, prediction_column, test_size = 0.3):
    self. Search = None
    self.X_train, self.X_test, self.y_train, self.y_test = train_test_split(train_df,
                                                                                train_df[prediction_column],
                                                                                test_size=test_size, random_state=7)
    

    self.X_train = self.X_train.drop([prediction_column], axis=1)
    self.X_test = self.X_test.drop([prediction_column], axis=1)

def tune_hyper_parameters(self, params=DEFAULT_PARAMS, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', kfold=10, n_iter=25):
    Kfold = KFold(n_splits=kfold)  
    lgbm = LGBMClassifier()
    self.search = BayesSearchCV(estimator=lgbm,
                                search_spaces=params,
                                scoring=scoring,
                                n_iter=n_iter, 
                                cv=Kfold,
                                verbose=0)

def train(self):
    result = self.search.fit(self.X_train, self.y_train)
    print("Best parameters:", self.search.best_params_)
    print("Best accuracy: ", self.search.best_score_)

    return result
```

I call it with:

```
lgbm_classifier = LightgbmClassifier(df = df.copy(), prediction_column = 'type')
lgbm_classifier.tune_hyper_parameters(scoring='accuracy')
lgbm_model = lgbm_classifier.train()
# Evaluate test score
```

When I run it a few times, the BayesSearchCV uses different hyperparameters with different scores.

also, changing the DEFAULT_PARAMS dict values (like replacing 'subsample_for_bin': [20000,50000,100000,120000,150000], with 'subsample_for_bin': [15000,50000,100000,120000,140000]) , and run it again, gives different scores. as the same, also changing other params, as test_size, n_iter, cv has the same effect.

My questions are:

1. Is it a good strategy to run the model multiple times, and find the hyperparams with the best scores, and then run it with them? for example, after running multiple times, I got the best score with test_size=0.2, subsample_for_bin: 50,000, 'min_child_samples': 20, etc. so now I will not use BayesSearchCV anymore to tune them, but just select them as they are?
   Or maybe it's a train-test contaminant, and requires a different strategy?
2. What if there is an improvement only in the test score or only in the cross-validation score?